# Python flask delete 500 internal server error

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm running into a 500 internal server error in my **DELETE** def:

```
def delete(self, flight_id):
    session = db.get_session()
    try:
        spend_for_flight = session.query(func.count(db.Snapshot.rowID))\
            .join(db.Flight, db.Flight.strategy_id == db.Snapshot.strategy_id)\
            .filter(and_(db.Snapshot.interval >= db.Flight.start_date, db.Snapshot.interval <= db.Flight.end_date, db.Flight.rowID == flight_id)).scalar();

        # there is spend for at least one of these flight dates
        if spend_for_flight > 0:
            response = jsonify(error="Flight has spend. Cannot delete.")
            response.status = 400
            return response
        elif spend_for_flight == 0:
            session.query(db.Flight).filter(db.Flight.rowID == flight_id).delete()
            session.commit()
            return 204
    except sqlalchemy.exc.SQLAlchemyError, exc:
        session.rollback()
        reason = exc.message
        response = jsonify(error=reason)
        response.status_code = 501
        return response
    finally:
        session.close()
```

The error is happening in the `if` statement.  The SQL alchemy query runs fine and `spend_for_flight` checks out (the else succeeds) and the flight deletes successfully.  When `spend_for_flight >0`, I get the server error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `status_code` instead of `status` like you did with the `501`. That is, instead of:

```
response.status = 400
```

write

```
response.status_code = 400
```

Comment: That did it, thanks for the second pair of eyes